# Is there any business in Santiago, Chile that rents cars on December 25 evening aside from the car rental businesses located at the SCL airport?

Tags: car-rentals, chile, santiago-de-chile

I had booked a car at [Santiago International Airport (SCL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arturo_Merino_Ben%C3%ADtez_International_Airport) with Budget but they actually didn't had any car for me when I arrived. None of the car rental businesses located at the SCL airport have any car available.

Is there any business in Santiago, Chile that rents cars on December 25 evening aside from the car rental businesses located at the SCL airport?

Comment: This is far too specific to be useful to almost anyone else. Even so, at 10:30pm on Christmas Day I'd guess that your answer is no.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass thanks, there are over 6 millions inhabitants in Santiago, I don't feel it's too specific to ask for car rental businesses that are opened on holidays. If the answer is no, then that's the answer.

Comment: Maybe not, but that's not what you asked

Comment: @Arthur'sPass so if I broaden the question from Christmas to any holiday is that broad enough?